# How to listen and process all MQTT messages in parallel with python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, mqtt

I'm using the [paho mqtt](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#known-limitations) python lib to listen to MQTT messages. We get about a thousand messages a second. I wrote a some simple code that's called when receiving a message. It fills up an array and handles them when it's batched up.

```py
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        message_buffer.append(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
        if(len(message_buffer) > 100):
            handleBuffer(message_buffer) # <-- Takes a few sec
            message_buffer.clear()
```

Since handling takes a few seconds, do I miss messages? Or does it make a designated listening thread? Couldn't really understand the docs so not sure how it works.

Is there a way I can make sure I'll *always* listen, and in parallel handle the messages without pausing the listening process?

Comment: Yes, it’s always a good idea to use one thread to receive the messages and push into a queue, and other worker threads to grab the messages from the queue and process them.

Comment: But threads are not guaranteed to always be running, they can be paused right? So since MQTT is a pub/sub protocol, and if you are not listening at all times you might miss messages...?

Comment: That's why you need to listen them for new messages all the time, which means the actual handing needs to delegated to other workers.

Comment: IMO, there are three functions that are independent from one another.
1. Grab new messages
2. Accumulate them in batches
3. Process these batches
I would try to have three independent components to do these, for maximum flexibility and performance.

Comment: When you say three independent components, what do you mean? Different programs? Different threads?

Comment: The function `handleBuffer` is really just a function that saved this to stream.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244077/discussion-between-arnab-de-and-norwegianclassic).